# Hide certain columns in a responsive data table using DT package

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to create a responsive data table for my shiny application using `DT` package. I want to hide certain columns in advance. For example:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris,extensions="Responsive"
    )
  }
)
```

This output gives me 5 columns. It only hides columns when I narrow the page. But, I want to hide last 3 columns in advance and I just want to see first two columns every time. Is there a way to do that?

**Update:**

Example output

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can hide columns in your table using DT options or extensions.

If you want them to be hidden in advance but have a button to make them visible again, the `ColVis` extension should work well for you: [link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html)

If you just want thme stay hidden, add the following option (can't remember where I've seen its documentation right now..)

```
options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=columns2hide)))
```

Comment: is it possible to use ColVis to hide some of the columns by default and once the user checks the box display them?

Comment: Third section on the posted link mixed with the code above should do the trick.

Comment: Note that when you fill in `colmuns2hide` you should but in the column number. Not sure if you can put in the column name.

Comment: you can’t, you have to do `match(columns2hide, colnames(iris))`, maybe with a `na.omit` wrapped around it if `columns2hide` could contain a column not available in the data

Comment: Note that DT's column index seems to start at 0, not 1, so it's `match(columns2hide, colnames(iris))-1L`.

Comment: hiding columns with `columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=columns2hide)` seems to be unstable. Any feedback from heavy users?

Comment: The column index can catch you off guard. It start from 0 but row name is counted as column 0. So the index depend on if you enabled row names.

Comment: I am trying to make the same thing work but am having issues. I am not sure what I should pass to targets. The data that is being rendered is a reactive object named "dataInput". I would like to hide multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

I have another way which I like for its readability.  It does not solve the problem of column numbering though.

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")
library(magrittr)
columns2hide <- match('Sepal.Width', colnames(iris))
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      {
        dataTableProxy(outputId = 'tbl') %>%
          hideCols(hide = columns2hide)
        iris
      },
      extensions="Responsive"
    )
  }
)
```

`dataTableProxy` creates a proxy object that you can operate on with a couple of functions (see `?dataTableProxy`).
It can be handy for hiding/showing/selecting/add/... rows and columns of the table when clicking on a button, for example.
Because it has `deferUntilFlush = TRUE` by default it waits with its handling of the table until its next generation.  In this case this simply happens on the following line.

Answer (score 1):

```
options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=columns2hide)))

colums2hide <- c('col_name_1','col_name_2')
```

This is how to do it with specifying column names vs column numbers.