# htmlOutput or data table. Which does not refresh properly?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.. Here what is going on:
When I run it for the first time and click on data table row I can see all character information as they should be. But then when I am selecting several other observations on the plot and click again on the same row, it still gives info about the one which was on that place previously (eg for the 1st row -> Luke Skywalker).

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# 1) Prepare layout


hair = starwars %>%
  select(hair_color) %>%
  arrange(hair_color) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  arrange(species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE),
      htmlOutput('txt')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)

# 2) Prepare data

srv <- function(input, output){

  starwars_data <- reactive({
    starwars_data_as_table <- as.data.frame(starwars)
    starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

    starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
    starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

    # a) add missing info

    starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      mutate(
        height = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
          name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
          name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
          TRUE ~ height
        ),
        mass = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
          name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
          name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
          TRUE ~ mass
        ),
        film_counter = lengths(films),
        vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
        starship_counter = lengths(starships)
      )

    colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                                 "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                                 "Birth", "Gender", 
                                 "Homeworld","Species", "Movies",
                                 "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                                 "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
    starwars_data

  })

  # filter data using input box
  starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

    dta <- starwars_data()
    if(length(input$hair) > 0){
      dta <- dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
    }
    if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    } 
    if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    }
    dta
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~Height,
        y = ~Homeworld,
        color = ~factor(Gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })


  selected_data = reactive({
    sel_data = starwars_data_filtered() %>%
      select(ID,
             Name,
             Height,
             Weight,
             Hair,
             'Birth',
             'Number of movies',
             'Number of vehicles',
             'Number of starships')
    ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")
    if(!is.null(ed)){
      sel_data = sel_data %>%
        filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
    }
    sel_data 
  })

  output$table = renderDataTable({
    d = selected_data()
    if(!is.null(d)){
      datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$txt = renderText({
    row_count <-  input$table_rows_selected
    if(!is.null(row_count)){

      # a function to create a list from the vector
      vectorBulletList <- function(vector) {
        if(length(vector > 1)) {
          paste0("<ul><li>", 
                 paste0(
                   paste0(vector, collpase = ""), collapse = "</li><li>"),
                 "</li></ul>")   
        }
      }

      # in starwars dataframe, vehicles and starships are lists
      # need to select the first element of the list (the character vector)
      vehicles <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Vehicles"][[1]]
      starships <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Starship"][[1]]
      movies <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Movies"][[1]]

      paste("Name: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Name"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Gender: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Gender"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Birth: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Birth"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Homeworld: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Homeworld"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Species: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Species"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Height: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Height"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Weight: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Weight"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Hair: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Hair"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Skin: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Skin"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Eyes: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Eyes"],"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Vehicles: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(vehicles),"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Starship: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(starships),"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Movies: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(movies),"<br>","</b>")
    }
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Your datatable is based on the `selected_data()` dataframe (which updates when you select points on your plot), but you're subsetting the original `starwars_data()` dataframe in `output$txt`. You're grabbing the row from a different dataframe than the one used for your datatable. So we'll need to use `selected_data()` in `output$txt`.

However, `selected_data()` doesn't contain all of the necessary columns (e.g. Movies, Starship, Vehicles) to produce your `output$txt`. Instead of choosing a subset of columns when you define `selected_data()`, we can just [hide the columns from the datatable output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32428537/8099834).

**Solution**

First, we'll get the index of the columns we want to hide. Here's an example of how we'd do that:

```
### select columns to remove based on columns we want to show ###
columns2show <- c("name", "birth_year", "mass", "vehicles") # columns to show
columns2hide <- which(!(colnames(starwars) %in% columns2show)) # column index to hide
colnames(starwars)[columns2hide] # check hidden columns
```

*Edit:* As krakowi pointed out, our column indexes are based on R, but the datatable is generated with javascript. Since R starts counting at 1, but javascript starts at 0, the original answer grabbed the incorrect columns in the datatable. So we'll need to subtract 1 from columns2hide to get the correct column indexes when counted by javascript. See below:

```
columns2hide <- columns2hide - 1
```

Then, we'll need to hide these columns from the datatable by adding `options`:

```
datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE, 
                  ## columns to hide ##
                  options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = columns2hide))))
```

Finally, in `output$txt`, we'll need to change `starwars_data()` to `selected_data()` so we're grabbing the row from the correct dataframe.

**Example**

Let's put it all together:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# 1) Prepare layout


hair = starwars %>%
    select(hair_color) %>%
    arrange(hair_color) %>% 
    distinct()


spec = starwars %>% 
    select(species) %>% 
    arrange(species) %>% 
    distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
            selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE),
            htmlOutput('txt')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput('plot'),
            dataTableOutput('table')
        )
    )
)

# 2) Prepare data

srv <- function(input, output){

    starwars_data <- reactive({
        starwars_data_as_table <- as.data.frame(starwars)
        starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
            tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

        starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
        starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
        starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
        starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

        # a) add missing info

        starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
            mutate(
                height = case_when(
                    name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
                    name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
                    name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
                    name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
                    name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
                    TRUE ~ height
                ),
                mass = case_when(
                    name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
                    name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
                    name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
                    name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
                    name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
                    TRUE ~ mass
                ),
                film_counter = lengths(films),
                vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
                starship_counter = lengths(starships)
            )

        colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                                     "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                                     "Birth", "Gender", 
                                     "Homeworld","Species", "Movies",
                                     "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                                     "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
        starwars_data

    })

    # filter data using input box
    starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

        dta <- starwars_data()
        if(length(input$hair) > 0){
            dta <- dta %>% 
                filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
        }
        if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
            dta <-  dta %>% 
                filter(Species %in% input$spec)
        } 
        if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
            dta <-  dta %>% 
                filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
                filter(Species %in% input$spec)
        }
        dta
    })



    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
                source = 'scatter') %>%
            add_markers(
                x = ~Height,
                y = ~Homeworld,
                color = ~factor(Gender),
                key = ~ID
            ) %>%
            layout(
                xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
                yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
                dragmode = "select"
            )
    })


    selected_data = reactive({
        # need to keep all columns from the original dataframe
        # to have necessary info for output$txt
        sel_data = starwars_data_filtered() 
        ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")
        if(!is.null(ed)){
            sel_data = sel_data %>%
                filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
        }
        sel_data 
    })

    output$table = renderDataTable({
        d = selected_data()

        # column names to show in datatable
        columns2show <- c("ID", "Name", "Height", "Weight", "Hair", "Birth",
                          "Number of movies", "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
        # column indexes to hide in datatable - subtract one to account for JS indexing
        columns2hide <- which(!(colnames(selected_data()) %in% columns2show))
        columns2hide <- columns2hide - 1

        if(!is.null(d)){
            datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE, 
                      ## columns to hide ##
                      options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = columns2hide))))
        }
    })

    output$txt = renderText({
        row_count <-  input$table_rows_selected
        if(!is.null(row_count)){

            # a function to create a list from the vector
            vectorBulletList <- function(vector) {
                if(length(vector > 1)) {
                    paste0("<ul><li>", 
                           paste0(
                               paste0(vector, collpase = ""), collapse = "</li><li>"),
                           "</li></ul>")   
                }
            }

            # need to subset dataframe that reacts to selecting points on plot
            # change starwars_data() to selected_data()

            # in starwars dataframe, vehicles and starships are lists
            # need to select the first element of the list (the character vector)
            vehicles <- selected_data()[row_count, "Vehicles"][[1]]
            starships <- selected_data()[row_count, "Starship"][[1]]
            movies <- selected_data()[row_count, "Movies"][[1]]

            paste("Name: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Name"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Gender: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Gender"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Birth: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Birth"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Homeworld: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Homeworld"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Species: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Species"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Height: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Height"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Weight: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Weight"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Hair: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Hair"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Skin: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Skin"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Eyes: ", "<b>",selected_data()[row_count,"Eyes"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Vehicles: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(vehicles),"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Starship: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(starships),"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Movies: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(movies),"<br>","</b>")
        }
    })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Your whole explanation step by step is really important to me to understand what is going on. I have started my R adventure over month ago, I sometimes struggle to see things as the whole.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am bothering but it looks like not all columns2show are displayed for datatable. Instead of Birth, Gender is showing and Number of movies is missing.

Comment: help not needed :) The thing is javascript starts indexing on 0 whereas R starts on 1 so subtracted 1 from columns2hide and works fine :)

Comment: Sorry to have missed that -- I'm glad you could solve it! I'll edit my answer to include your point. I'm happy to help and hope you're having fun learning R!