# R Shiny - Show/Hide Data Table (DT) columns

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to incorporate something like this: https://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/examples/api/show_hide.html into my R Shiny application.

I'm unfamiliar with how to incorporate the JS into R, but showing/hiding columns doesn't necessarily need to function like this. It could be a drop down (`selectInput`) with the column headers where the user could select multiple choices in order to hide those specific columns. Or even check boxes to hide/show them.

Just looking for a way for the user to have control over what columns are hidden in a DT.
My options would look like this: `options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=columns2hide)))`, just need a way to fill `columns2hide`.

See: [Hide certain columns in a responsive data table using DT package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409194/hide-certain-columns-in-a-responsive-data-table-using-dt-package/32428537)

Comment: I found by adding ```extensions = 'Buttons',``` and ```dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list(list(extend = 'colvis', text='Column Picker', columns = c(1:19, 23:24)))``` to my DT, it creates a Button above my DT that allows me to show/hide specific columns.

Comment: Problem now is that I have some JS, ```tags$style(HTML(".table table tbody td:nth-child(n+23) {pointer-events: none;} .table table tbody td:nth-child(n+23)>div {pointer-events: auto;}"))``` that disables double-clicking cells to edit them (since some of my columns in my DT are editable) . The JS contains nth-child which changes when I hide columns and then refers to a different column. How can nth-child change dynamically?